# Implicit function for a convex gradient.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

Let $Q \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ denote a convex function with $g(x) = \nabla Q(x)$ well-defined. I am interested in defining the following variables
\begin{eqnarray}
c & = & x - g(x) \\
d & = & x + g(x) 
\end{eqnarray}
and then writing $c$ as a function of $d$. My approach is as follows:

1. Let $h(x) = x + g(x)$. We need to show that the function $h^{-1}$ is well-defined.
2. Apply chain rule. Using the notation $[J_{x}c](d)$ to denote the Jacobian of $c$ with respect to $x$ evaluated at $d$, we have
   \begin{eqnarray}
   [J_d c](d) & = & [J_x c](h^{-1}(d)) \ [J_d h^{-1}](d).
   \end{eqnarray}
3. Standard methods of finding a primitive function that is consistent with the Jacobian $[J_d c](d)$ may be applied.

My main concern is with step 1. My attempt is as follows. We assumed $Q$ to be convex, so each entry $g_i(x)$ is non-decreasing in $x_j$ for each $j$. The entry $h_i$ is the sum of $x_i$ which is strictly increasing and $g_i$ which is non-decreasing. Therefore $h^{-1}$ is well defined and $x = h^{-1}(d)$. Is this reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"so each entry $g_i(x)$ is non-decreasing in $x_j$ for each $j$": This is not true.

But the function $g$ is monotone and, thus, $h$ is strongly monotone. Invertibility of $h$ follows then from the [theorem of Browder-Minty on monotone operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browder%E2%80%93Minty_theorem).

Comment: Thank you, gerw. Could you point me to understand how $h$
 which directly adds the identity function is bounded? I would guess I'm missing something simple (but deep) in the theorem you have provided.

Comment: I am not directly sure, why the English wiki requires the operator to be bounded or what bounded means in that content. You might want to check a different source, e.g. a book on nonlinear functional analysis (or the German wiki https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satz_von_Minty-Browder).